# Need help distinguishing between a primary and secondary source

Tags: dna, genomics

I am trying to figure out if the [following article](http://genome.cshlp.org/content/20/5/547.full.pdf) is a primary or secondary source.

I'm leaning towards secondary but here are my cases for both.

> **Primary**: Published in a peer-reviewed journal.
>
> **Secondary**: It seems to be mostly a summary of other works so it might
>   not be original research.

Can anyone confirm this for me? Thank you!

Comment: probably better on Academia?

Comment: This would be a better fit on academia.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment: Although this is a review article which summarizes the findings of other researchers, considers this as a primary article. The author gives you all the resources he used in the reference section of this article and summarises their finding. Additionally, review articles in renowned journals (and Genome Research is definitely such a journal) are peer-reviewed. Primary vs. secondary sources would be more the comparision of research articles and news articles. In my observation, news articles hardly ever name the sources or the original articles about which they report. Plus they sometimes have problems of getting the message wrong.